# How can I remove all azure integration from my visual studio templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I never notests this but if you create a new asp.net MVC website in visual studio you get full azure integration without knowing it. Turns out all of my applications, while hosted on my own server, are logging everything they do with Azure.

If I remove all azure dependencies from my project it won't build anymore. Is there a way to remove this feature from my asp.net project template? I really don't like this, for one, my inbox is exploding with "Data collection for .... has reached it's daily cap" emails and two, I feel violated in my privacy, why does Microsoft have know everthing of my projects?

Sorry for the possible duplicate question, but Google really isn't my friend on this one.

Comment: It is Application Insights you are talking about. Remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, when you create a new project with default options you don't get any Azure integrations.

If your application is with Azure AD authentication, you should disable this when creating the new project.

If your application is doing logging on Azure, you can disable Application Insights.